# InvalidOperationException not being caught in lambda expression

Tags: c#, exception, lambda

I am catching an `InvalidOperationException` around this use of `XmlSerializer.Deserialize`. Strange thing is that when I provide it with malformed XML it does indeed throw an `InvalidOperationException` on that line but it is not caught by the catch block.

My first assumption is that it is something strange with exception handling in lambdas but I was unable to find anything conclusive upon searching.

Anyone have thoughts?

Also, please note, this code does work with non malformed XML. Also, the `InvalidOperationException` are in the same namespace of `System`

```
    XElement xmlElement = GetElement("users");
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));        
    try
            {
                return xmlElement.Descendants("user").Select(x => (User)deserializer.Deserialize(x.CreateReader()));
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                //XmlSerializer almost always throws this ambiguous exception but its inner exception is much more explicit
                //creating a new exception with the message of the old to ensure there isn't a circular throw-catch of InvalidOperationException
                throw new XmlException(e.InnerException.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Is it being thrown on xmlElement.Descendants() call? Have you tried to return the value outside the catch block using some temporary variable? And do not forget that you are returning query, not its result.

Comment: What does the XML look like that causes the exception?

Comment: The `Select` is executed in the `try` but the lambda isn't, it gets executed when the result is used. Have you tried adding `.ToList()` at the end and see what happens?

Comment: +1 @Tallmaris you were right as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how the return value is used, but `Select` is lazy that only executes the lambda when the result collection is enumerated. I think that's why the `catch` does not work - at the time when the exception is thrown, it's already out of the `catch` block.

Adding `ToArray` to the end should force it to execute immediately:

```
return xmlElement.Descendants("user").Select(x => (User)deserializer.Deserialize(x.CreateReader())).ToArray();
```

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.